# Writing constraints for grid squares in python z3

Tags: python, z3, z3py

So I'm working with Z3 in python and I have to write constraints/conditions for a "marvellous square" which is just a grid of numbers. the conditions for a marvellous square are:

1. It is filled with all the integers from 1 to **2
2. Every row in the square sums to the same number t
3. Every column in the square also sums to that same number t
4. Both diagonals sum to that same number t

Using the list constraints I've been been able to do the first 1:

```
aGrid = [ [ Int("x_%s_%s" % (i+1, j+1)) for j in range(n) ] for i in range(n) ]

conditionOne = [ And(1 <= aGrid[i][j], aGrid[i][j] <= n**2) for i in range(n) for j in range(n) ]
```

So in line 1 I create the instance for an n-by-n grid.
In line 2, I create the first condition where each of the entries is from 1 to n squared

The issue I have now is getting the sum of each column and row and equating them to the same thing in the same constraint. As well as the diagonal constraints. I have a feeling they will all be done in the same constraint, but the list comprenhension is confusing.

Comment: No need to do everything in one constraint. Just write them all separately; that'll be easiest. Note that you also need to state that all the numbers in are different from each other. Your condition 1, as stated right now, does not do this; it allows duplications.

Comment: That makes sense. But how do I access the elements for the diagonal and column constraints? I have done the row constraints but the diagonal and column ones are trickier.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```py
from z3 import *

# Grid size
n = 4

# Total and grid itself
t = Int('t')
grid = [[Int("x_%s_%s" % (i+1, j+1)) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

s = Solver()

# Range constraint
allElts = [elt for row in grid for elt in row]
for x in allElts: s.add(And(x >= 1, x <= n*n))

# Distinctness constraint
s.add(Distinct(*allElts))

# Each row
for row in grid: s.add(t == sum(row))

# Each column
for i in range(n): s.add(t == sum([grid[j][i] for j in range(n)]))

# Each diagonal
s.add(t == sum([grid[i][i]     for i in range(len(grid))]))
s.add(t == sum([grid[n-i-1][i] for i in range(len(grid))]))

# Solve:
if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print(f't = {m[t]}')
    for row in grid:
        for elt in row:
            print(f'{str(m[elt]):>3s}', end="")
        print("")
else:
    print("No solution")
```

When I run this, I get:

```
t = 34
  7  4 14  9
 11 16  2  5
  6 13  3 12
 10  1 15  8
```

Which satisfies the constraints.

Note that as `n` gets larger the time z3 will spend in solving will increase quite a bit. Here're are two ideas to make it go much faster:

- Note that `t` depends on `n`. That is, if you know `n`, you can compute `t` from it. (It'll be `n * (n*n + 1) / 2`, you can justify to yourself why that's true.) So, don't make `t` symbolic, instead directly compute it and use its value.
- Computing over `Int` values is expensive. Instead, you should use bit-vector values of minimum size. For instance, if `n = 6`, then `t = 111`; and you only need 7-bits to represent this value. So, instead of using `Int('x')`, use `BitVec('x', 7)`. (It's important that you pick a large enough bit-vector size!)

If you make the above two modifications, you'll also see that it performs better than `Int` values only.

Comment: For the row and column constraints, can they be written like this instead:                                         row = [ (sum(grid[i]) == t) for i in range(n) ]
col = [  (sum([grid[j][i] for j in range(n)]) == t) for i in range(n)  ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Also do you possibly have discord where we can have a longer chat?

Comment: And for this: for row in grid: s.add(t == sum(row))                                                                     Wouldn't this be flagged as invalid syntax because the "s.add(t == sum(row))" isn't indented under the for loop? You used for a couple of the other constraints as well. What does it mean?

Comment: Your first comment: Those wouldn't add the constraints; but make a list. I'm not sure what you're getting at. Your second comment: If a for-loop has a single-line body, you can directly put it in the same line; no need to go to the next line and indent. You can easily test this yourself by putting the program in a file and run python on it.